# strncpy seg fault, but am able to assign string manually

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, strncpy

I have a global pointer to char arrays defined (on the stack I believe?) as:

```
char *history[BUFFER_SIZE];
```

And inside a method I simply want to:

```
strncpy(history[0], str, length);
```

and it seg faults. It doesn't make sense to me since:

```
history[0] = "a string"
```

doesn't seg fault.

My questions:

1. Since I am defining the array of char arrays like this, I shouldn't have to do any sort of malloc or initialization, correct?
2. Why is it seg faulting?

Comment: `history[0] = "a string"` is a pointer to a *string literal*. Writing to that with `strncpy` or any other way is complete no-no. But the question is unclear. If you did not allocate memory to `history[0...]` so that data can be copied to it, `strncpy(history[0], str, length);` will fail.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`char *history[BUFFER_SIZE];` is an array of `char*`s that point to nowhere. When you try to `strncpy` to those pointers, you invoke undefined behavior (because they point to nowhere), and you're seeing this manifested as a segfault.

When you `history[0] = "a string"` this assigns the `char*` at `history[0]`, so `history[0]` no longer pointer to nowhere, it points to `"a string"`.  `"a string"` is a string literal, stored elsewhere in your program, most likely the read-only section. `history[0]` does not actually contain the data `"a string"`, it simply contains the address of where `"a string"` resides.

> Since I am defining the array of char arrays like this, I shouldn't
>   have to do any sort of malloc or initialization, correct?

That depends on what you want to do.  It's perfectly fine to do `history[0] = "a string"`, just know that trying to modify that string is also undefined behavior, since it is a string literal.  If you want to copy the string literal to a section of memory where you can freely modify the copy, you will have to allocate some memory with `malloc` or similar.  But `char *history[BUFFER_SIZE];` isn't defining an "array of `char` arrays", it's defining an array of `char` pointers.

Comment: Ahh I think I understand now. So if I want to "statically" (not sure its meaning) define the array without malloc, I can do:

char history[BUFFER_SIZE][str_len]; and then assign history[0] = "..." as I did before? That way, I allocate the length beforehand. It seems to be working now

Comment: @Zhinkk yes, if you don't want to use `malloc`, then the compiler needs to know how much space you want at compile time. If you do something like `char history[BUFFER_SIZE][MAX_WORD_LENGTH];`, then you can `strcpy` up to `BUFFER_SIZE` words of up to `MAX_WORD_LENGTH-1` characters each to your array (`MAX_WORD_LENGTH-1` because c strings must have a `NUL` terminator).

Comment: @Zhinkk use `strcpy` as you were before as long as "a string" isn't longer than `str_len` The `=` operator does not copy strings.

Answer (score 1):

history is an array of pointers, you can not copy a whole string to what is only likely 32b or 64b in size.

You must in fact allocate memory to be associated with the pointer, whether it be on the stack or heap. The second example you gave allocated memory for the string before assigning it's address to the pointer stack.